# Content Security Policy not working in Vue application

Tags: html, vue.js, content-security-policy

I'm adding a Content Security Policy to two websites I'm working on, a Vue application and a static HTML site. I want to disallow people from loading my sites in an iFrame. For my HTML project I just added this CSP meta tag to the `index.html` file:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-ancestors 'self'">`

And that worked perfectly. However, I can't replicate the same behavior in my Vue app. There's an `index.html` file in my public folder, I assumed this meta tag would go there, but it changes nothing in the site's behavior (it can still be loaded in an iFrame).

I've referred to the following stack overflow posts for help:

[Content security policy to be added in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76880025/content-security-policy-to-be-added-in-vuejs)

[How to add CSP header (Content-Security-Policy) to vuejs app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224438/how-to-add-csp-header-content-security-policy-to-vuejs-app)

[Handling CSP with Vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193904/handling-csp-with-vue-js)

But they seem to either be making the same assumption that I am (meta tags can go in `public/index.html`) or they show how to implement with Express, which I am not using in this project.

I've also tried different configurations like with "X-Frame-Options" but it didn't work either.

I can provide more details if necessary.  Thanks